# How can I rename value node animation references in the dope sheet editor?

Tags: animation, materials, dopesheet

I made a simple material animation, and the animated value nodes are represented in the dope sheet and graph editors as Default Value (Value) [image]

which is not very specific, I had renamed and relabeled my nodes, but it did not effect the dope sheet editor?

So how I can rename the *Default Value (Value)* lines?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to rename the "Default Value (Value)" labels directly. However, you can put them in a group. Select the references then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to create a labeled group.

[image]
*The groups are highlighted green in this image*